# MATLAB - How to display the position of a value in an array

Tags: matlab

For example, I have a set of test scores placed in an array. On MATLAB, how do I  display text indicating that the first value of the array is 'Student 1', the second value is 'Student 2' and so on that would work no matter how many test scores I place in it?

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
grades = round(unifrnd(1, 10, [100,1]));
for istud = 1: length(grades)
    fprintf ('student %i \t grade: %i\n', istud, grades(istud))
end
```

What you get is

```
student 1    grade: 5
student 2    grade: 9
student 3    grade: 9
student 4    grade: 5
student 5    grade: 7
student 6    grade: 8
student 7    grade: 6
student 8    grade: 7
student 9    grade: 8
student 10   grade: 6
student 11   grade: 3
student 12   grade: 7
```

and so on

if you want to write it to a file and not only the screen use

```
fid   = fopen('grades.txt','w');
for istud = 1: length(grades)
    fprintf (fid,'student %i \t grade: %i\n', istud, grades(istud))
end
fclose (fid)
```